# Check if a trait is implemented or not

Tags: rust, traits

How to check if a struct implement some trait and **calculate boolean result**.

For example:

```rust
struct Foo;
struct Bar;

trait Qux {}
impl Qux for Foo {}
const fn is_qux<T>() -> bool { ... }

assert!(is_qux::<Foo>());
assert_ne!(is_qux::<Bar>());
```

Comment: I don't believe this is currently possible. The unstable specialization feature may make it possible, though.

Comment: @cdhowie, Which unstable specialization feature ?

Comment: [This one](https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/unstable-book/language-features/specialization.html). Basically it allows otherwise-conflicting `impl`s if certain conditions are met, such that there is always one "best" `impl` for a given type. This would allow you to `impl` for all `T` but have a second impl for `T where T: Qux`, for example, and the second would be picked when `T` implements `Qux`, and otherwise the first would be picked.

Comment: Why would you want that? Just out of curiosity. Like, if it do not implements the trait the compiler is gonna complain anyway...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I know three ways to implement that. None is perfect.

The best way is to use [specialization](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/31844):

```rust
#![feature(specialization)]

const fn is_qux<T: ?Sized>() -> bool {
    trait IsQuxTest {
        const IS_QUX: bool;
    }
    impl<T: ?Sized> IsQuxTest for T {
        default const IS_QUX: bool = false;
    }
    impl<T: ?Sized + Qux> IsQuxTest for T {
        const IS_QUX: bool = true;
    }
    
    <T as IsQuxTest>::IS_QUX
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=1c9cea35bd2e6f924f93dee08cd73c9b).

However, this solution has multiple problems:

- It is nightly-only, and specialization doesn't have a clear path toward stabilization.
- [**Specialization is unsound**](https://aturon.github.io/blog/2017/07/08/lifetime-dispatch/). The soundness problem does not apply to this specific case, however it is good to be careful, and also...
- Current specialization is imprecise. This is for the same reason it is unsound: when used with lifetimes, the compiler may not choose the correct `impl`. For example:

```rust
fn foo<'a>(v: &'a String) {
    struct Foo<'a>(&'a String);
    impl Qux for Foo<'static> {}
    println!("{}", is_qux::<Foo<'a>>());
}

fn main() {
    let v = String::new();
    static S: String = String::new();
    print!("is_qux::<Foo<'static>>() = "); foo(&S);
    print!("is_qux::<Foo<'non_static>>() = "); foo(&v);
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=69f2abe583ba0ae4bfb0fc46e7db7ed6).

Output:

```
is_qux::<Foo<'static>>() = true
is_qux::<Foo<'non_static>>() = true // ???
```

The next solution is to use [deref specialization](https://github.com/dtolnay/case-studies/blob/master/autoref-specialization/README.md) or specialize based on the facts that inherent methods are picked before trait methods, if possible, as suggested by @Aiden4. Unfortunately, like said, this does not work with generics.

The last approach is the most interesting: it exploits *existing specializations in the standard library*. For example, [arrays implement `Clone`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.59.0/src/core/array/mod.rs.html#341-351), but if the element type implements `Copy`, [they use bitwise copy to clone themselves](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.59.0/src/core/array/mod.rs.html#366-371) (as this is faster). However, `Clone` is not required to do the same as `Copy` (although strongly advised to do so) - and this fact makes this behavior observable, and allows us to use the following neat trick (the idea is from [here](https://internals.rust-lang.org/t/rc-uses-visibly-behavior-changing-specialization-is-that-okay/16173/16?u=chrefr)):

```rust
fn is_qux<T: ?Sized>() -> bool {
    use std::cell::Cell;
    use std::marker::PhantomData;

    struct IsQuxTest<'a, T: ?Sized> {
        is_qux: &'a Cell<bool>,
        _marker: PhantomData<T>,
    }
    impl<T: ?Sized> Clone for IsQuxTest<'_, T> {
        fn clone(&self) -> Self {
            self.is_qux.set(false);
            IsQuxTest {
                is_qux: self.is_qux,
                _marker: PhantomData,
            }
        }
    }
    impl<T: ?Sized + Qux> Copy for IsQuxTest<'_, T> {}

    let is_qux = Cell::new(true);
    _ = [IsQuxTest::<T> {
        is_qux: &is_qux,
        _marker: PhantomData,
    }]
    .clone();

    is_qux.get()
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=02d82d02555968e45f3dce913c24c8e1).

It can be adjusted to many specializations in std, for example [this one](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/b8c56fa8c30821129b0960180f528d4a1a4f9316/library/alloc/src/sync.rs#L2210-L2211).

This solution uses specialization under-the-hood, and so [specialization's caveat #3 still applies](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=f2e8d89a173b7f9a0e31ac796389baa6). It uses existing specializations, however, and so usable on stable - and furthermore, it is thus also completely sound. However, it has another caveat: I'm not sure Rust's stability guarentees apply in this case, and thus it may break in the future. In addition to that, this solution is not `const` - though it may become if the relevant functions will be `const`ified in the future.

Answer (score 4):

## You can do this, but not in a generic context

Because inherent methods are preferred over methods in traits, you can write a macro taking advantage of the fact to determine if a specific type implements a specific trait.

```rust
macro_rules! is_trait{
    ($name:ty, $trait_name:path)=>{{
        trait __InnerMarkerTrait{
            fn __is_trait_inner_method()->bool{
                false
            }
        }
        struct __TraitTest<T>(T);
        impl<T:$trait_name> __TraitTest<T> {
            fn __is_trait_inner_method()->bool{
                true
            }
        }
        impl<T> __InnerMarkerTrait for __TraitTest<T>{}
        __TraitTest::<$name>::__is_trait_inner_method()
    }}
}
fn main() {
    println!("{}", is_trait!(i32, Copy)); //true
    println!("{}", is_trait!(String, Copy)); //false
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=b558c95dbfd26a7374f12f84d879e0ce)

However, this won't work in a generic context, because the method selection is done before monomorphization. So the function

```rust
fn is_copy<T>() -> bool{
    is_trait!(T, Copy)
}
```

will always return false. It may be possible to do better with specialization, but I would not go that route, especially if you are new to rust, because specialization is currently unsound.

Comment: Just to inform, There is a crate called [impls](https://github.com/nvzqz/impls) which could be used...

Comment: @Stone Really great job with the crate! Works perfectly with what I need! Thank you!